# How to write .net web api controller to consume and expose another web api

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to wrap an api call with my own api to avoid CORS and so I can avoid exposing credentials to the client. Can anyone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

This works in a webform but I don't know how to put its an api controller class.
When I try to return the objects with the code below it throws an error

Controller:

```
public class sampleController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<sample> GetSample() 
    {

        string url = String.Format("sampleurl.json");
        WebRequest requestObj = WebRequest.Create(url);
        requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("USER", "PW");
        requestObj.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
        responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
        string str = null;
        using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        sample sampleList = (sample).ser.Deserializer(str, typeof(sample));

        return sampleList.Root_Object;

    }    

}
```

Model:

```
public class sample
{
    public List<Root_Object> Root_Object {get; set;}
}

public class Root_Object
{
    public string listItemOne { get; set; }
    public string listItemTwo { get; set; }
}
```

JSON

```
{
  "Root_Object": [
    {
      "ListItemOne": "Value",
      "ListItemTwo": "Value"
    },
    {
      "ListItemOne": "Value",
      "ListItemTwo": "Value"
    },
    {
      "ListItemOne": "Value",
      "ListItemTwo": "Value"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expected to be able to return all objects from Root_Object. The return statement gives me an error of

> "Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<project.Models.Root_Object>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<project.Models.sample>'`. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to deserialize from the API?

Comment: @BrianRogers I've updated with the JSON. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianRogers I tested your solution and had planned on accepting your answer since it was more exact. It is just a pass through api. You deleted your post though.

Comment: OK, I have restored my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `GetSample()` method is supposed to be a pass-through API, meaning you don't intend to change the JSON format at all, then you need to make two changes:

1. Change the return type of your method from `IEnumerable<sample>` to `sample`
2. Change the method to return `sampleList` instead of `sampleList.Root_Object`.

If you're instead trying to "unwrap" the list of objects, then the other two answers are correct.

Comment: This was the more precise answer based on the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be returning `IEnumerable<Root_Object>` as the type? You currently have it as `IEnumerable<sample>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method requires a `return` type of `IEnumerable<sample>`, but you are returning `sampleList.Root_Object`, which is itself a list of Root_Object

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it!